# Issue in hide and show of combobox in struts2

Tags: struts2

I have a jsp page in which I have two combobox and one radio button of struts tag.
Now depending on the value of radio button  I have to hide one combobox .
How can I achieve this in struts2. I can easily do if this tag are simple HTML by hiding a div tag. But struts tag are not hide by this jquery.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to hide it by struts2? or by jquery?
Cause this would be totally different

In case you are trying to hide from struts2 - use `<s:if>` tag - just check the value of radio button, and either render or not.

In case of jquery all you have to do is find html element id, something like `($idToHide).hide();`